# using rails how do I import CSV onto mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to import CSV files into my `mongodb` Using Ruby on Rails.
I know how to do it from the shell/terminal but not how to do it from Rails

Comment: Please give some detail, what you tried.

Comment: Show us the commands you use on the commandline, what you tried in Rails and any error messages you might have gotten.

Comment: If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this tutorial as an example [**Using MongoDB to store and retrieve CSV files content in Ruby**](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2012/10/using-mongodb-to-store-and-retrieve-csv-files-content-in-ruby/), you can store all the values as strings, so you only need to read the CSV file and MongoDB dynamically creates all the needed attributes in objects that should represent each file row for the given CSV file:

```
class StoredCSV
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  def self.import!(file_path)
    columns = []
    instances = []
    CSV.foreach(file_path) do |row|
      if columns.empty?
        # We dont want attributes with whitespaces
        columns = row.collect { |c| c.downcase.gsub(' ', '_') }
        next
      end

      instances << create!(build_attributes(row, columns))
    end
    instances
  end

  private

  def self.build_attributes(row, columns)
    attrs = {}
    columns.each_with_index do |column, index|
      attrs[column] = row[index]
    end
    attrs
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
StoredCSV.import!('data.csv')
stored_data = StoredCSV.all
```